# How can I use filters on specific header row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Probably I can not express it, let me upload a screenshot [this is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj3kg.png) and I do not want to use filters at Ch. section but when I delete filters, excel does delete all filters.

Comment: Don't delete all filters, just clear the filter on the column instead.

Comment: @Isolated I do not do it on purpose it does automagically.

Comment: Do you want to clear any applied filter on the column? Or, do you want the filter button to not exist on the column?

Comment: @TylerN Not exist

Comment: I doubt if it can be hidden for a specific column. Filter is either all or nothing. You could try putting the data inside an Excel table. Press control + T to create the table and ctrl+shift+L to toggle filters (probably the whole header though)

Comment: Try to change the Table to Range and select the column you need and add the Filter for the column.

Answer (score 1):

*If you don't want the "Auto Filter Drop down sign" to appear on any particular column, in your case is 4th column i.e. Ch, then you need to use VBA Macro.*

**:Caveat:**

*Macro is the only possible method to fix the issue.*

---

```
Sub AutoFilter()

With Range("A1")
.AutoFilter Field:=1, VisibleDropDown:=Ture
.AutoFilter Field:=2, VisibleDropDown:=True
.AutoFilter Field:=3, VisibleDropDown:=True
.AutoFilter Field:=4, VisibleDropDown:=False    
.AutoFilter Field:=5, VisibleDropDown:=True

End With

End Sub
```

---

**How it works:**

- To get the VB editor either press **Alt+F11** or select the Sheet TAB then **R**ight Click and hit **V**iew Code.
- **Copy** & **Paste** this code as Standard module.
- Now press **Alt+Q** to return to the Sheet.
- **Save** the Workbook as Macro Enabled *.xlsm.
- Finally **RUN** the Macro.

**N.B.**

*You find that the Filter Drop Down sign doesn't
appears on column 4, i.e. Ch.*

*To make in normal, hit Filter command from DATA menu.*

*Adjust Field numbers and Filter Range as needed.*

Comment: Hey @Anonim ,, now check my post I'm sure this is what you were looking for,, if this solves the issue then you may [Mark it as answer](https://superuser.com/tour)  as well Up vote. Please do reply through comments in case of further issues ☺